# Schrödinger's Equation with square potential

Tags: matlab, quantum-mechanics

I have written some code to solve and plot the time independent Schrödinger's equation with potential x^2, which has a bound state with odd integral energy eigenvalues. My code plots the graphs up to some finite x value. When I input the energy eigenvalue to be 2.9995, the wavefunction seems to increase to infinity but when I input 3.0005, it decreases to negative infinity.

I have justified this as being expected by the 'tail wag' argument - i.e. in between we expect a normalisable bound state, i.e. when E=3.

But how can I be sure that the graph will continue to increase/decrease monotonically?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It probably depends at least a little on the algorithm you use to invent a fictional wavefunction from an incorrect eigenenergy. For starters, it sounds like you've ensured the wavefunction will be real (which isn't the case in general), but haven't forced it to be $\ge 0$. Without knowing more about how you do that, it's unclear what if anything its sign means. Have you looked at what the square modulus does?

Comment: I guess my question is : why is the 'wag the tail' argument valid? How do we know there is a bound state solution between the two energy eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

If you have studied the finite square well, you know that only solutions with energy exactly equal to the  eigenvalue go to $0$ at $\infty$ . For other energies they blow up exponentially (in at least one direction). This is the same phenomenon.

Instead of trying to calculate the eigenfunction at $t = 0$ by solving the equation, you could use the analytic form of the function (available in most QM texts).

Comment: I'm not sure a *finite* square well was intended here; I think the SHO is considered, in units of $\hbar\omega/2$. However, the outcome is, in the details you mentioned, basically the same.